# How to get exchange email without outlook client

Tags: linux, command-line, windows-7, exchange-server

Where I work, we use MS exchange for our corporate email and my unix servers dump a lot of status/system/error messages into my mailbox. Mostly, these messages are benign but once in a blue moon, a critical message gets overlooked because of the sheer volume.

I want to be able to access my exchange email (via IMAP, as I presume it is the only supported protocol) with a command line tool. I have DOS shell, PowerShell, AutoHotKey at my disposal on a windows 7 professional workstation and have access to Solaris 10 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 5 on many servers I manage on the UNIX side.

I read a lot of documents elsewhere on the web in the past and tried one or two of these solution to no positive results.

I am looking for a tried and true solution from the community members. Unfortunately, the exchange support in my organization is very unresponsive and they only deal with outlook client deficiencies. Rest of the requests, they dismiss as out-of-scope. So I am on my own in this battle.

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions

Comment: Probably better to ask this on Serverfault or Superuser. At present, it's all pretty cludgy, but you can get things working with some effort. You CAN get Exchange mapi working (not just imap). Some find the Gnome Evolution works. Others use the non-free ExQuilla extension for Thunderbird for email and the free Lightning + exchangeserver (Ericsson's git repo version) add-ons for Exchange calendar/appointments. The Thunderbird route works for me. Also, some say DavMail works well, but you'll just get basic imap/pop.